# How should we respond to unanswered but solved problems?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, unanswered-questions

When reading through the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468682/md5-hash-values-not-matching), I found out that the problem had already been resolved, though no answer was given. Apparently the cause of the problem was the OP's oversight only.

Should a question like this be flagged? If so, with what type of flag? Not a real question or not constructive? Why?

Or should one add an answer of the form "There was no problem in the question, OP was making some mistake elsewhere" or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should probably be closed as "too localized". Given the comment made by the OP, there is not much hope for anyone to come in and actually resolve the issue. Or to really identify what the issue is. As such, it has become a problem relevant (or even known) to the OP only and is too localized.

Feel free to vote accordingly if you have that privilege, or flag for moderator attention with a clear explanation of what you saw.

Comment: I was confused, because it is natural to make some mistake and when unable to sort out tending to ask others and sometime problem is solved just after asking (and due to asking). So it should not be considered to ask a question int these circumstances unfair. So should not be downvoted.

Comment: Whether or not you downvote is entirely up to you. I personally wouldn't in this case. The close vote is enough IMO, but those who feel a downvote is deserved are free to do so.